# Solve $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}x^{x^x-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}x^{x^x-1}$$

**Note:- I have solved this problem and below is the solution but I am searching for the better approach**

My attempt is as follows:-

$x^x$ is indeterminate form $(0^0)$ as $x$ tends to $0^{+}$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}x^{x^x-1}=e^{\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\left(x^x-1\right)ln(x)}\tag{1}$$

Let's assume $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\left(x^x-1\right)ln(x)=y$

$$y=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\left(e^{x\ln x}-1\right)\ln x\tag{2}$$

As $x$ tends to $0^{+}$, $x\ln x$ is the indeterminate form $(0\cdot\infty)$

So first let's see what this indeterminate form actually tends to

$$z=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}x\ln x$$

Assume $t=\ln x$

$$z=\lim_{t\to -\infty}e^tt$$
$$z=\lim_{t\to -\infty}\dfrac{t}{e^{-t}}$$

So we are getting $\dfrac{-\infty}{\infty}$ and we can apply L's Hospital rule here

$$z=\lim_{t\to -\infty}\dfrac{1}{-e^{-t}}$$

$$z=0$$

So going back to equation $(1)$, now we can say as $x$ tends to $0^{+}$, $x\ln x$ tends to $0$

$$y=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\left(e^{x\ln x}-1\right)\ln x\tag{3}$$

$$y=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\dfrac{\left(e^{x\ln x}-1\right)}{x\ln x}\cdot x\ln^2 x$$

$$y=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\dfrac{\left(e^{x\ln x}-1\right)}{x\ln x}\cdot x\ln^2x$$

$$y=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}x\ln^2x$$

$$y=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\dfrac{ln^2x}{\dfrac{1}{x}}$$

So we have $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$ form here and so we can apply L's hospital rule here

$$y=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\dfrac{2\ln x\cdot\dfrac{1}{x}}{\dfrac{-1}{x^2}}$$

$$y=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\dfrac{2\ln x}{\dfrac{-1}{x}}$$

Again applying L's hospital rule here as we have $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$ form

$$y=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\dfrac{\dfrac{2}{x}}{\dfrac{1}{x^2}}$$
$$y=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}2x$$
$$y=0$$

Putting value of $y$ back in equation $(1)$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}x^{x^x-1}=1$$

So lots of ups and down in this problem, can it solved by any simpler means?

Comment: Well, you assumed that the limit exists (and called it $y$) but didn't actually use that assumption which means the overall logic is fine. It is a little confusing and unnecessary as you can do the same limit analysis from your answer without defining $y$

Comment: I did that, so that steps will be clear.

Answer (score 3):

$$x^{x^x-1}=e^{(x^x-1)\ln{x}}=e^{\frac{e^{x\ln{x}}-1}{x\ln{x}}\cdot x\ln^2{x}}=e^{\frac{e^{x\ln{x}}-1}{x\ln{x}}\cdot4\left(\sqrt{x}\ln\sqrt{x}\right)^2}\rightarrow e^0=1.$$

Comment: its the same way, I did it, so its not what I was searching for.

Comment: @user3290550 I used that $x^x\rightarrow1$ for $x\rightarrow0^+$. It's a bit of different,

Comment: I will not argue here, but I also proved that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\ln x=0$, which is same $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x=1$

Comment: @user3290550 You proved that $x\ln^2x\rightarrow0.$ It's harder.

Comment: yeah, right, I could have used the fact that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}xln x=1$ which I calculated previously.

Comment: @user3290550 I saw it. I showed   that $x\ln^2x\rightarrow0$ follows from $x^x\rightarrow1$.

Comment: no, I got it, you made a mistake, you can't write $xln^2x=(\sqrt{x}\ln \sqrt{x})^2$, can you see that in your solution?

Comment: @user3290550 I wrote $x\ln^2x=4\left(\sqrt{x}\ln\sqrt{x}\right)^2$. See please better.

Comment: ok, yeah thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another use of LH: since $\frac{x^x-1}{1/\ln x}\sim\frac{x^x(\ln x+1)}{-1/(x\ln^2x)}=-\underbrace{x\ln^3 x}_{\to0}\underbrace{\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln x}\right)}_{\to1}\underbrace{x^x}_{\to1}\to0$, your limit is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\lim_{x\to0^+}x^{x^x-1}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^{x^x}}{x}\overset{\text{L'H}}{=}\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{d}{dx}(x^{x^x}).$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: this is a wrong way , as you have not proved that $x^{x^x}$ tends to $0$, because only then we can apply L'hospital here.

Comment: To you, is that fact not a given?

Comment: yes this is not given in a question.

Comment: But can **you** _easily_ see why it is true?

Comment: not easily, as we are getting indeterminate form, can you explain how easily you can see that this tends to zero

Comment: You have shown in your work that $x^x$ tends to $1$.  Logically, $x^{x^x}$ would tend to $0$ (i.e.we'll have $0^1$).

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to0^+}x^{x^x-1}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^{x^x}}{x} = \lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^{e^{xlog(x)}}}{x} $

Now, 
$\lim_{x\to0^+} xlog(x)  = \lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{log(x)}{\frac{1}{x}}\overset{\text{L'H}}{=} \lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{-1}{x^2}} = 0$

When we plug that back in, we get

$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^{x^x}}{x} = \lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^{e^{0}}}{x} = \lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^1}{x} = 1$